# React Select does not update until second option chosen

Tags: reactjs, select

Within my recipe app, I want users to be able to filter on various options (newest recipes, oldest, alphabetical, reverse alphabetical). A user can select an option, but once the option is selected, it doesn't update the order of recipe cards displayed. However, if you go into the dropdown and selected a new option, it will update and filter the recipes based on the previous selected option. Basically what is being displayed is always one behind what option is actually selected.

I'm leaving some code that is within my component out that I do not think is relevant.

```
export default function Recipes(props) {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [recipesListDefault, setRecipesListDefault] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('Newest');

  useEffect(() => {
    let sortedRecipes = []
    switch (filter) {
      case 'Newest':
        sortedRecipes = recipes.sort((a,b) => (a.created_at > b.created_at) ? -1 : 1)
        break;
      case 'Oldest':
        sortedRecipes = recipes.sort((a,b) => (a.created_at > b.created_at) ? 1 : -1)
        break;
      case 'Alpha':
        sortedRecipes = recipes.sort((a,b) => (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : -1)
        break;
      case 'Reverse Alpha':
        sortedRecipes = recipes.sort((a,b) => (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) ? -1 : 1)
        break;
      default:
        sortedRecipes = recipes
    };
    setRecipes(sortedRecipes);
  }, [filter]);

  const filterRecipes = (event) => {
    setFilter(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
              <MDBCol md="6" style={{marginTop: "1.25em"}}>
                <div>
                 <select
                  className="browser-default custom-select"
                  value={filter}
                  onChange={filterRecipes}
                >
                   <option value="1" disabled>Order Recipes by...</option>
                   <option value="Newest">Newest</option>
                   <option value="Oldest">Oldest </option>
                   <option value="Alpha">Alphabetical A-Z</option>
                   <option value="Reverse Alpha">Alphabetical Z-A</option>
                 </select>
               </div>
             </MDBCol>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're calling setRecipes and passing it the array it already has, You didn't change any value or only changed part of its values but it's still the same array. That's why React doesn't see any reason to re-render the component. An easy way to solve this issue is by spreading your array into a new array

```
setRecipes([...sortedRecipes]);
```